# Jest test suites failed to pass

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing, jestjs

The issue appears when I'm running all tests at once and every time the amount of failed test suites is different. When I'm running failed test suites separately tests pass successfully. Stack trace leads to *node_modules* dependencies. Here is a part of a jest log:

```
 FAIL  tests/unit/middleware/organization.middleware.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Invalid URL: http://localhost

      at new URLImpl (node_modules/whatwg-url/dist/URL-impl.js:21:13)
      at Object.exports.setup (node_modules/whatwg-url/dist/URL.js:54:12)
      at new URL (node_modules/whatwg-url/dist/URL.js:107:22)
      at transformOptions (node_modules/jsdom/lib/api.js:235:38)
      at new JSDOM (node_modules/jsdom/lib/api.js:34:15)

 FAIL  tests/unit/services/logstash.service.test.js
● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Invalid URL: http://localhost

      at new URLImpl (node_modules/whatwg-url/dist/URL-impl.js:21:13)
      at Object.exports.setup (node_modules/whatwg-url/dist/URL.js:54:12)
      at new URL (node_modules/whatwg-url/dist/URL.js:107:22)
      at transformOptions (node_modules/jsdom/lib/api.js:235:38)
      at new JSDOM (node_modules/jsdom/lib/api.js:34:15)
```

I have the following dependencies installed:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@xmpp/client": "^0.11.1",
    "accesscontrol": "^2.2.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "^2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.1.4",
    "express-rate-limit": "^5.1.3",
    "express-validator": "^6.12.0",
    "geoip-lite": "^1.3.8",
    "got": "^11.5.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "log4js": "^6.3.0",
    "mongo-mock": "^4.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.2.7",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "node-cache": "^4.2.1",
    "node-schedule": "^1.3.2",
    "p-retry": "^4.2.0",
    "pako": "^1.0.11",
    "saslprep": "^1.0.3",
    "search-query-parser": "^1.5.4",
    "sinon": "^9.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.22",
    "eslint": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.3.5",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "mongodb-memory-server": "^6.9.6",
    "node-mocks-http": "^1.10.1",
    "nyc": "^14.1.1",
    "proxyquire": "^2.1.3",
    "randomstring": "^1.1.5",
    "rewire": "^5.0.0",
    "rewiremock": "^3.14.3",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3"
  },
  "jestSonar": {
    "reportFile": "test-results.xml"
  }
```

Comment: I have the exact same error, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

To fix the issue I updated `jest` version to `27.0.6`

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue and managed to fix it by disabling cache when running jest, looks like the cache is corrupted.

Try passing an argument to npm test like this:

```
npm test -- --no-cache
```

or run jest directly

```
jest --no-cache
```